# Range de um Array em SWIFT

Tags: array, ios, swift, range

Tenho um array de bytes e preciso descobrir em que faixa (startindex e endindex) um byte esta ou se só tem o startindex

ex:

```
var Faixa1:Array<UInt16> = [2,4,6,8,10,11,12]
var Faixa2:Array<UInt16> = [1,2]

var Valor1:UInt16 = 2
var Valor2:UInt16 = 3

//valor1 na faixa1
//startindex: 2
//endindex: 2

//valor1 na faixa2
//startindex: 2
//endindex: 2

//valor2 na faixa1
//startindex: 2
//endindex: 4
```

Comment: A pergunta me parece um pouco confusa. O Array é de bytes ou de inteiros? O array é sempre ordenado? Você busca os índices no array ou o valor imediatamente anterior e posterior ao valor buscado? Se possível insira também o código que você desenvolveu para resolver o problema, mesmo que não esteja funcionando.

Comment: é um array de bytes ordenado, eu tenho o bloco de código em Java, estou passando essa implementação pro swift, nada que eu desenhei chegou a funcionar, então não tenho nada

Comment: @H.Cardoso pode colocar o código em Java ajuda muito